# "There is no default constructor available in android.database.sqlite.SQLitepenhelper" in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, constructor, default, sqliteopenhelper

Trying to extend class with SQLiteOpenHelper, but this error shows up : "There is no default constructor available in android.database.sqlite.SQLitepenhelper" along with other "cannot resolve symbol Category, Note,..."

```
class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(Category.getSql());
        db.execSQL(Note.getSql());
        db.execSQL(Attachment.getSql());
        db.execSQL(CheckItem.getSql());
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Category.TABLE_NAME);
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Note.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Attachment.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CheckItem.TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to define an explicit constructor yourself that calls the 4- or 5-arg `super` constructor in [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

For example:

```
public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "database.db", null, 1);
}
```

where `database.db` is your database file name and `1` is the version.

Comment: I had the same question about the WebView class, but this answered my question anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your `DBHelper` child then this post help, othervise you can allready understandfirst Define it like this one in outside of you class, means uperside...

```
private DBHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
```

Then use this

```
class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VIRSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(Category.getSql());
    db.execSQL(Note.getSql());
    db.execSQL(Attachment.getSql());
    db.execSQL(CheckItem.getSql());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Category.TABLE_NAME);
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Note.TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Attachment.TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CheckItem.TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}
```

And then try this context for your parent class

```
public MyDatabase(Context c){
    ourContext=c;
}
```